# How to access my SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So I followed this guide (http://www.civicactions.com/blog/2010/may/25/how_set_svn_repository_7_simple_steps) to create a SVN repository on my Ubuntu 14.04 remote server.  The location is `/home/user/SvnRepositories/SpringTestRepo`.

I'm trying to perform a Checkout on this repo from Tortoise SVN on my Windows machine, but I'm not sure what the URL is to access this repo.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run ifconfig on the ubuntu machine to get the IP address, then use that: svn+ssh://username@machine.ip.address/home/username/SvnRepositories/SpringTestRepo

That should get you connected as long as everything's working :)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you :) In the past I was used to using SVN's that are only in URL format, so it was strange to me seeing other examples I found that look similar to yours.